# 2D Limit Question: Calculation Disagrees W/ WolframAlpha

Tags: limits, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x(1+2x/y)}{(1+x/y+(x/y)^{2})^{2}}.$$

When I use WolframAlpha, it tells me the limit doesn't exist.  However, if I change to polar coordinates I get

$$
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x(1+2x/y)}{(1+x/y+(x/y)^{2})^{2}} = \lim_{r\to 0^{+}}\frac{r\cos(\theta)(1+2\cot(\theta))}{(1+\cot(\theta) + \cot^{2}(\theta))^{2}} = 0
\end{equation*}
$$

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: Did you specify $x,y$ real?

Comment: Maybe a bug?? Unders MMA V11.2 & Linux `Limit[x*(1 + 2*x/y)/(1 + x/y + (x/y)^2)^2, {x -> 0, y -> 0}]` returns 0 as expected

Comment: A workaround for your W|A input may be to replace $(x,y)$ with $(x^2,y^2)$ to force the variables to be real. Then you get the [correct result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5Bx%5E2*(2x%5E2%2Fy%5E2%2B1)%2F(1%2Bx%5E2%2Fy%5E2%2Bx%5E4%2Fy%5E4)%5E2,+%7Bx,+y%7D+-%3E+%7B0,+0%7D%5D).